# Upload an image to a file with php

Tags: php, file-upload

I want to upload an image to a file using php. I keep simplifying the code but it still doesn't work. I'll add back parameters once I figure out what's wrong. Here's my file upload.php

```
<html>
<body>

<form action="upload.php" method="post" enctype="multipart/form-data">
    Select image to upload:
    <input type="file" name="upload" id="upload">
    <input type="submit" value="Upload Image" name="submit">
</form>

</body>
</html>

<?php
if(isset($_POST["submit"])) {
$pathway= "uploads/";
$target_file = $pathway . basename($_FILES["upload"]["name"]);
    if (move_uploaded_file($_FILES["upload"]["tmp_name"], $target_file)) {
        echo "The file ". basename( $_FILES["upload"]["name"]). " has been uploaded.";
    }
}
?>
```

I've created the folder "uploads", but images are not added to it.

Comment: Whats the permission of uploads folder ?

Comment: Permission? I'm using Godaddy as a host and both uploads and upload.php are under the same directory.

Comment: http://php.net/manual/en/function.error-reporting.php

Comment: so, what did that ^ throw back? and permissions, meaning is the folder writeable to it?

Comment: you're going to need to ping one of us. I can't keep staring at this question waiting for an update. Put yourself in our shoes and you'll see what I mean. We posted comments to get clarification and trying to help, but we're sitting here..... waiting. It might sound like impatience to you, but again; put yourself in our place. I have left the question, good luck. I really hope you find the problem.

Answer (score 0):

first you have to make sure that the attribute file_uploads = on in your php.ini 
file

second make sure to set the upload_max_filesize to the size you want

then see this code

```
<?php
$target_dir = "uploads/";
$target_file = $target_dir . basename($_FILES["fileToUpload"]["name"]);
$uploadOk = 1;
$imageFileType = pathinfo($target_file,PATHINFO_EXTENSION);
// Check if image file is a actual image or fake image
if(isset($_POST["submit"])) {
    $check = getimagesize($_FILES["fileToUpload"]["tmp_name"]);
    if($check !== false) {
        echo "File is an image - " . $check["mime"] . ".";
        $uploadOk = 1;
    } else {
    echo "File is not an image.";
    $uploadOk = 0;
    }
    }
// Check if file already exists
if (file_exists($target_file)) {
    echo "Sorry, file already exists.";
    $uploadOk = 0;
 }
// Check if $uploadOk is set to 0 by an error
if ($uploadOk == 0) {
    echo "Sorry, your file was not uploaded.";
    // if everything is ok, try to upload file
 } else {
      if (move_uploaded_file($_FILES["fileToUpload"]["tmp_name"], $target_file)) {
      echo "The file ". basename( $_FILES["fileToUpload"]["name"]). " has been uploaded.";
} else {
     echo "Sorry, there was an error uploading your file.";
     }
}
?>
```